# How to get substring between two substrings?

Tags: php, substring, preg-match-all

I want to extract a substring between two substrings. The problem is that it will extract only the first one. I want to do it in all of my document.

Example :

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}

$document = '<a data-id="777777"></a><a data-id="888888"></a><a data-id="99999"></a>';
$content = $document;
$start = '<a data-id="';
$end = '"';
$data = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
echo $data;

$document2 = '<a data-A="AAAAAA"></a><a data-A="BBBBBB"></a><a data-A="CCCCCC"></a>';
$content = $document2;
$start = '<a data-A="';
$end = '"';
$data2 = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
echo $data2;
```

Now it's extracting only `777777` `AAAAA`. But what I want is `777777` `AAAAAA` `888888` `BBBBBB` `999999` `CCCCC`

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: I got some trouble doing this. Is there another way to achieve this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function.

Example:

```
<?php
$document = '<a data-id="777777"></a><a data-id="888888"></a><a data-id="99999"></a>';
$document2 = '<a data-A="AAAAAA"></a><a data-A="BBBBBB"></a><a data-A="CCCCCC"></a>';

$list1 = [];
$list2 = [];
preg_match_all('/<a data-id="([^"]+)"/', $document, $list1);
preg_match_all('/<a data-A="([^"]+)"/', $document2, $list2);
print_r([$list1, $list2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a75ddbc08b44bc5bcec0c95e7839f479819c6fbe))

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    return preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($start,'/').'\K[^'.preg_quote($end,'/').']*(?='.preg_quote($end,'/').')/',$content,$out)?$out[0]:'';
}


$document = '<a data-id="777777"></a><a data-id="888888"></a><a data-id="99999"></a>';
$content = $document;
$start = '<a data-id="';
$end = '"';
$data = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
var_export($data);

$document2 = '<a data-A="AAAAAA"></a><a data-A="BBBBBB"></a><a data-A="CCCCCC"></a>';
$content = $document2;
$start = '<a data-A="';
$end = '"';
$data2 = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
var_export($data2);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '777777',
  1 => '888888',
  2 => '99999',
)array (
  0 => 'AAAAAA',
  1 => 'BBBBBB',
  2 => 'CCCCCC',
)
```

My method effectively produces this pattern: `/<a data-id="\K[^"]*(?=")/` which returns the desired substrings as fullstring matches.  Not only does this pattern perform with fewer steps because it is without a capture group, it returns a smaller result array.  [Pattern Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/LQc9wJ/1)

`preg_quote()` is used to escape all necessary characters so that the variable pattern doesn't "break".

`$end` is used twice in the pattern -- once in the "negated character class" `[^"]` and a second time in the "positive lookahead" `(?=")`

Just for the record:

- `/"([^"]*)"/` will work on your sample input.
- When handling html strings, it is recommended to use html parsers: DomDocument, etc.

---

*Important, my pattern is only built to handle `$end` as a single character.  If it is more than one character, then the pattern will not work as expected and will need to be modified.

This is a slightly slower pattern / `preg_match()` call that will allow larger `$end` strings:  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQc9wJ/2))

```
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($start,'/').'\K.*?(?='.preg_quote($end,'/').')/',$content,$out)?$out[0]:'';
```

Comment: Your are welcome.  I am happy to provide a robust and optimized answer with explanation.  It will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that your sample input poorly resembles your real input, so it is difficult to guess the level of accuracy that you actually require.

I will off a highly stable technique that does not rely on regex surgery.  Note that `data-` attributes are expected to be in all lowercase in a valid html document.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DZQj4))

```
function getValue($html, $tag, $attr) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument; 
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($xpath->query("//{$tag}[@{$attr}]") as $node) {
        $result[] = $node->getAttribute($attr);
    }
    return implode(',', $result);
}

$html = '<a data-id="777777"></a><a data-id="888888"></a><a data-id="99999"></a>';
$tag = 'a';
$attr = 'data-id';
echo getValue($html, $tag, $attr);

echo "\n---\n";

$html = '<a data-A="AAAAAA"></a><a data-A="BBBBBB"></a><a data-A="CCCCCC"></a>';
$tag = 'a';
$attr = 'data-a';
echo getValue($html, $tag, $attr);
```

Output:

```
777777,888888,99999
---
AAAAAA,BBBBBB,CCCCCC
```